# What is $\bigcup_{\mathcal a \in \mathcal I} (\mathcal A _\mathcal a)$ if $\mathcal I =\emptyset$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

What is $\bigcup_{\mathcal a \in \mathcal I} (\mathcal A _\mathcal a)$ if $\mathcal I =\emptyset$?

Is it $\emptyset$? I can't think of how to reason through this question. Could the answer potentially be $\mathcal A _\mathcal a$ with $\mathcal a=\emptyset$? I can't think of what that would even mean.

Comment: The answer could literally be anything since you did not define one singe symbol

Answer (score 6):

Unpacking the definition, we have
$$\bigcup_{a \in \mathcal{I}} \mathcal{A}_a = \{ x \mid \exists a \in \mathcal{I},~ x \in \mathcal{A}_a \}$$
When the index set $\mathcal{I}$ is empty, the statement $\exists a \in \mathcal{I},~ x \in \mathcal{A}_a$ is false for all $x$, and so $\displaystyle \bigcup_{a \in \mathcal{I}} \mathcal{A}_a$ is empty.